# Apriori algorithm -Find 2 of combination

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an `Order` table like this:

```
   ORDER_ID PRODUCT_ID
     1        1230
     1        1231
     1        1232
     2        1231
     2        2000
     3        1230
     3        3567
```

and a `Product` table:

```
  PRODUCT_ID NAME
   1230       A
   1231       B
   1232       C
```

My first question, how to get combination of 2 Product Table, then how my new table structure should be?

for example;

```
{1230,1231}, {1230,1232}, {1231,1232}
```

but I don't want to this `{1231,1230}` because it already added.

Second one, in `Order` table, I keep sold product one session. How will be my new table?

example;

```
orderid     products
1          {1230,1231,1232}
```

Finally, I want to find product other sold together support value, 
`exp: {1231,1230} count : 2
      {1230,1232 count : 0  }`

thanks in advance.

edit: i want to do like this: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~zaiane/courses/cmput499/slides/Lect10/sld054.htm

Comment: What are "dual combinations" ?? E.g. why is `{1230,1232}` included?? What are you really trying to achieve?? It's not very clear at all....

Comment: Are you just trying to find all combinations of 2 products that have been sold together and how often this has occurred?

Comment: i want to do this:http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~zaiane/courses/cmput499/slides/Lect10/sld054.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have interpreted your requirement correctly?

```
;WITH T(P1, P2, ORDER_ID)
     AS (SELECT p1.PRODUCT_ID,
                p2.PRODUCT_ID,
                O.ORDER_ID
         FROM   Product p1
                JOIN Product p2
                  ON p1.PRODUCT_ID < p2.PRODUCT_ID
                JOIN [ORDER] o
                  ON o.PRODUCT_ID IN ( p1.PRODUCT_ID, p2.PRODUCT_ID )
         GROUP  BY p1.PRODUCT_ID,
                   p2.PRODUCT_ID,
                   O.ORDER_ID
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
SELECT P1,
       P2,
       COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM   T
GROUP  BY P1,
          P2
```

Comment: i don't understand why you put COUNT(*) = 2

Comment: Because we are looking for orders that have both products. I have assumed each `PRODUCT_ID` can only appear once per order. If this is not the case you could use `COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) = 2` instead. No idea how closely this answer corresponds to the link you posted though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand questions 2 or 3, so please clarify in your question.

The first one is tricky, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p1, products p2 GROUP BY ((p1.PRODUCT_ID*p2.PRODUCT_ID)+p1.PRODUCT_ID+p2.PRODUCT_ID)
```

Because it would group by rows only where the two numbers are the same, without caring about order. There might be a more elegant way to create what's basically a unique id for that combination, but I can't think of any.